# Java: Representing a large amount of data arrays

Tags: java, arrays, memory, enums

For a work scheduling application I need to generate a lot of possible employee schedules for w weeks (= 7w days). An employee schedule consists of a list of shifts (early, late, night, day off) for each day of the planning period. The application is programmed in Java.

At this time, I represent an employee schedule as follows:

```
public class Schedule
{
    /** List with for every day of planning period the assigned shift */
    private Shift[] shiftlist = new Shift[Settings.schedule_days];

    /** Cost of schedule (for measuring its quality) */
    private double cost;

    // A list of variables, representing schedule properties
    // which are referenced often.
    // E.g.: number of workweekends, number of night shifts

    // Also some methods for updating / retrieving information
}
```

Shift is an enum representing the assigned shift, defined as:

```
public enum Shift
{
    DAY, LATE, NIGHT, FREE;
}
```

I also have some shift properties in the enum declaration and methods to compare properties, but I don't think that is relevant here.

Every employee has a list of his possible Schedules:

```
public class Employee
{
    /** Large set of possible schedules for planning period */
    public LinkedList<Schedule> generated_schedules;

    // Variables representing properties of employee
}
```

My problem is that I actually have 50 employees and I would like to generate 100.000 -- 1.000.000 possible schedules per employee.

Schedules are actually generated quickly and since I have 8GB of memory available in my computer, I can store a lot of them. However, when finished generating for 30--40 employees, my memory gets full.

A suggestion somebody gave me is to use an array of chars to represent the assigned shifts instead of an array of enums. This would utilize less space.
Furthermore, he stated that using a list of char arrays instead of a list of Schedule objects is also better. But, then it is not possible to save the schedule properties (such as cost) somewhere near the schedule and they need to be recalculated often. I think this will be a serious drawback.

Does this observation indeed make sense or do you think there is a better way to express this large amount of data in order to use less space?

Comment: Do you need to keep all generated schedules in memory at the same time? What are you doing with them? Is it not possible to generate and process them one after the other (and forgetting the previous one)?

Comment: The schedules are created for individual employees, according to their preferences. A selection of the schedules is iteratively added to a Linear Program using column generation. The LP tries to select a roster for every employee, such that the staffing demands are fullfilled. Therefor, I need all schedules in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need all schedules in memory at the same time, then the most space-efficient encoding would be to use a BitSet with 2 bits per day.

```
public class BitSetShiftList {
  private BitSet bitset;

  public void BitSetShiftList(int size) {
    bitset = new BitSet(size * 2);
  }

  public void setShift(int day, Shift shift) {
    int ordinal = shift.ordinal();
    assert ordinal >= 0 && ordinal <= 3;

    bitset.set(day * 2, (ordinal & 0x1) != 0);
    bitset.set(day * 2 + 1, (ordinal & 0x2) != 0);
  }

  public Shift getShift(int day) {
    int ordinal = (bitset.get(day * 2) ? 0x1 : 0x0) |
      (bitset.get(day * 2 + 1) ? 0x2 : 0x0);
    return Shift.values()[ordinal];
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks like an efficient idea! This uses only 2 bits instead of 16 bits a char uses. Thank you very much, I will investigate this approach. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce memory, you need to determine what is using the most memory currently and what assumptions you might be able to make about that data type which would make it smaller.  Without this information, you would just be guessing.

---

I suggest you use a generic algorithm based approach.

For example;

- You can generate only 1000 schedules and rate them.
- The top 500, you keep
- Use these to mix together to generate the next 1000 with some random mutations.

repeat until your best scores are not improving.

The point is; you can use another approach to produce far less schedules in less time but still converge to an optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you, but this kind of scheduling approaches have been researched often. I am currently researching another approach for which I need more schedules. I know I can reduce the number of schedules in various ways, but for my approach I want to keep more in memory. The way to generate schedules is outside the scope of my question. What I want to know is if using char arrays and less Schedule-objects give a better performace.

Comment: The answer is possibly, but until you have used a memory profiler its impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

One experience in similar "small" projects:

Using an **embedded database** storing also in the file system, is advisable. Though SQL is ugly, it allows better queries than hand-coded collection walks; and is easier to maintain.

With that the issue of memory consumption is moot.

If you want you might use JPA, for instance eclipseLink with ORM.